# want to set an ls alias, to take parameters

Tags: bash

i have the following alias set in my .bashrc:

```
alias la='ls -laG'
```

but i would really like to issue a command thusly:

```
la foo/bar
```

i guess i have to write a shell script? or is there some xargs way?

Comment: You could have tried it before asking :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me.  It will replace `la` with `ls -laG`, such that your command will be executed as `ls -laG foo/bar`.

Answer (score 2):

For your task you do not need parameters. (Or did I miss something?) However, you could write a shell function that take arguments. I use to have something like

```
function ccd () { mkdir -p $1 && cd $1; }
```

in my `.bashrc`. So I can (c)reate and (c)hange (d)ir in one step by typing

```
ccd temp1
```